Convert string to PDF ASP.NET MVC
I use these two functions to convert the string I pass into a PDF file and then download it. However, when I download a large string, the web crashes immediately, so how do I fix my code? to convert and download the string I send into a PDF file (the process still goes smoothly if the string is short in length).
This is my code:
public byte[] GeneratePdfFromString(string text) 
{ 
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) 
    {
        using (iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document()) 
        { 
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);        
            document.Open();
            document.Add(new Paragraph(text));
            document.Close();
        }

        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}

public IActionResult DownloadFile(int articleId, string[] imageUrls, string bodyText)
{
    var articleFolderPath = Path.Combine(_hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Resource", "Article",      articleId.ToString());
    var zipFilePath = Path.Combine(hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "fileDownloaded", $"article{articleId}.zip");

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(zipFilePath))
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(zipFilePath);
    }

    using (var archive = ZipFile.Open(zipFilePath, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(articleFolderPath))
        {
            foreach (var filePath in Directory.GetFiles(articleFolderPath))
            {
                var entryName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                archive.CreateEntryFromFile(filePath, entryName);
            }
        }

        foreach (var imageUrl in imageUrls)
        {
            var imageName = Path.GetFileName(imageUrl);
            var imagePhysicalPath = Path.Combine(_hostEnvironment.WebRootPath,     imageUrl.TrimStart('/'));

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(imagePhysicalPath))
            {
                archive.CreateEntryFromFile(imagePhysicalPath, imageName);
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bodyText))
        {
            var pdfBytes = GeneratePdfFromString(bodyText);
            var entryPathInArchive = $"article_body.pdf";
            var entry = archive.CreateEntry(entryPathInArchive, CompressionLevel.Optimal);

            using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
            {
                entryStream.Write(pdfBytes, 0, pdfBytes.Length);
            }
        }
    }

    return PhysicalFile(zipFilePath, "application/zip", $"article_{articleId}.zip");
}

